# How do I view an extremely large DGML (Visual Studio)?

Tags: visual-studio, include, visual-studio-2022, directed-acyclic-graphs, dgml

For context, I generated a 72MB DGML file that contains include file dependencies for the entire Unreal Engine solution by using the Architecture->Generate Graph of Include Files option.

Unfortunately, it is too large for VS to handle:

"Graph Too Large
The DGML document is probably too large to be be displayed because the total number of nodes and links exceeds 25,000.  If you attempt to display this graph the process could run out of memory.

Graph Details:
53,318 Nodes
380,327 Links
"

I need a way to view this extremely large DGML file, since Visual Studio fails to open the file even after 30 minutes on a 16 core processor.

**Potential Solutions**

- Allocate more memory to Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. I do not think an option like this exists, the estimated memory usage hovers around 4-6GB as expected. It would be great to allocate more RAM as you would JetBrains IDEs.
- Get a 3rd party DGML viewer that can handle super large files